# Применение алгоритмов Люка и Брезенхема для решения задачи отрисовки букв

Tags: алгоритм

Доброе время суток всем! Есть задание,связанное с использованием алгоритмов Брезенхема и Люка. То есть необходимо выполнить отрисовку первой буквы фамилии (Л) с использованием процедур генерации отрезков по методу Люка.
Выполнить отрисовку последней буквы имени (Й)  с использованием процедур генерации отрезков по методу Брезенхэма.
Буквы задать координатами концов отрезков, их образующих, в символьных матрицах 50х80 точек. 
Буквы отобразить горизонтально, рядом, в центре экрана, через «пробел» (пустая символьная матрица). Для этого использовать процедуру пересчета координат концов отрезков символьных матриц в экранные координаты в зависимости от используемого видеорежима. Цвета отображения букв – разные (любые).

Сами алгоритмы Люка и Брезенхема впринципе ясны , но хотелось бы вышей подсказки, на каком языке лучше всего писать такое приложение; как применимы алгоритмы генерации отрезков для рисования букв;  что подразумевается ввиду - буквы задать координатами концов отрезков, их образующих, в символьных матрицах 50х80 точек.
Сами алгоритмы имеются, алгоритм Люка:

```
#define  Xd 80
#define  Yd 245
#define  Xf 200
#define  Yf 100

int Dx,Dy,Cumul;
int Xinc,Yinc,X,Y;
int col;

{
  int Dx,Dy,Cumul;
  int Xinc,Yinc,X,Y;
  int col;
  int i;

  X = Xd; Y = Yd;  col = 4;
  putpixel(X,Y,col);
  if (Xd < Xf) Xinc = 1; else Xinc = -1;
  if (Yd < Yf) Yinc = 1; else Yinc = -1;
  Dx = abs (Xd - Xf);
  Dy = abs (Yd - Yf);

  if (Dx > Dy)
         {
         Cumul = Dx/2;
         for (i=0; i < Dx; i++)
                {
                X = X + Xinc;
                Cumul = Cumul + Dy;
                if ( Cumul >= Dx)
                  {
                  Cumul = Cumul - Dx;
                                Y = Y + Yinc;
                  }
                putpixel(X,Y,col);  
                }
         }
  else
         {
         Cumul = Dy/2;
         for (i=0; i < Dy; i++)
                {
                Y = Y + Yinc;
                Cumul = Cumul + Dx;
                if ( Cumul >= Dy)
                  {
                  Cumul = Cumul - Dy;
                                X = X + Xinc;
                putpixel(X,Y,col); 
                }
         }
```

Алгоритм Брезенхема:

```
#define  Xd 480
#define  Yd 345
#define  Xf 200
#define  Yf 100


{
  int Dx,Dy,Dx2,Dy2,Dxy,S;
  int Xinc,Yinc,X,Y;
  int col, i;

  col = 5;

  if (Xd < Xf) Xinc = 1; else Xinc = -1;
  if (Yd < Yf) Yinc = 1; else Yinc = -1;
  Dx = abs (Xd - Xf);
  Dy = abs (Yd - Yf);
  Dx2 = Dx + Dx; Dy2 = Dy + Dy;
  X = Xd; Y = Yd;
  putpixel (X, Y, col);   

  if (Dx > Dy)
         {
         S = Dy2 - Dx;
         Dxy = Dy2 - Dx2;
         for (i=0; i < Dx; i++)
                {
                if ( S >= 0)
                  {
                  Y = Y + Yinc;
                  S = S + Dxy;
                  }
                else S = S + Dy2;
                X = X + Xinc;
                putpixel (X, Y, col); 
                }
         }
  else
         {
         S = Dx2 - Dy;
         Dxy = Dx2 - Dy2;
         for (i=0; i < Dy; i++)
                {
                if ( S >= 0)
                 {
                 X = X + Xinc;
                 S = S + Dxy;
                 }
                else S = S + Dx2;
                Y = Y + Yinc;
                putpixel (X, Y, col);  
                }
         }
```

Comment: Ваш алгоритм уже реализован на си, пусть будет на си.

Comment: То есть реализован?  А как же тогда условия, поставленные мне в задании? например, символьная матрица 50 * 80 пикселей...

Answer (score 0):

> на каком языке лучше всего писать такое приложение

На чём проще, на том и пишите

> как применимы алгоритмы генерации отрезков для рисования букв

Буквы состоят из отрезков, кривые составляются из нескольких отрезков

> что подразумевается ввиду - буквы задать координатами концов отрезков, их образующих, в символьных матрицах 50х80 точек.

Возьмите бумагу в клеточку, толстым маркером нарисуйте упрощённые буквы, посмотрите координаты концевых клеток